# Como actualizo el salario de un empleado con el salario de otro empleado dentro de la misma tabla?

Tags: mysql

tengo la tabla `empleados(codigo,apellido,salario)` con los siguientes registros:

```
primer registro: (1,'arroyo',5000)
segundo registro: (2,'munguia',9000)
```

necesito actualizar el salario del empleado arroyo con el salario del empleado munguia sin importar cual sea el salario de munguia, es decir si el salario de munguia sufre algún incremento.

yo se que el modo fácil seria:

```
update empleados set salario=9000 where apellido='arroyo'
```

Pero que pasaría si el salario de munguia cambia, necesitaría que la consulta busque automáticamente el salario de munguia y se lo ponga a arroyo.

No se si me explico?

Agradecería cualquier ayuda que me pudieran brindar para resolver este caso...

Comment: Esta dirección puede ayudarte. Ahí explican cómo hacerlo aplicando un Inner Join.
https://supirole.com/mysql-phpmyadmin-actualizar-tabla-desde-otra-tabla/

Comment: Hola user148805, el enlace que me indicaste es lo mas parecido a lo que quiero, el único inconveniente es que lo hacen con 2 tablas distintas(Libros y Editorial) y en mi caso es dentro de la misma tabla(empleados). como hago eso mismo pero con una sola tabla, es decir, la actualización es entre 2 registros de la misma tabla.

Comment: Hola a todos, encontré esta solución a mi problema en sql server me funciono muy bien, pero no me funciono en sqlite, la consulta seria asi: update empleados set empleados.salario=b.salario from empleados inner join empleados b on empleados.apellido='arroyo' and b.apellido='munguia'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que busca podría ser algo así:

```
update  empleados 
    set salario = e2.salario
    from empleados e1
    inner join empleados e2
        on e2.apellido='munguia'
    where e1.apellido = 'arroyo'
```

Usamos una consulta de actualización para obtener el salario de `munguia` y lo usamos para actualizar el salario de `arroyo`

Comment: Hola Patricio Moracho, así fue como lo intente hacer, pero da error, al parecer el error me indica que no se puede usar en el SET una subconsulta para actualizar un campo.

Comment: Es cierto @Maynor , olvidé que es `mysql`, prueba con una consulta de actualización ya edité mi respuesta

Comment: Eso es correcto Patricio Moracho, así me funciona de maravilla, muchísimas gracias...

Answer (score -1):

El esquema que muestras y lo que quieres a mi parecer necesitaras generar una tabla adicional, donde registres por ejemplo (por así decir) `Igualar_Salario (empleadoSBase, empleadoSDestino)` ambos campos del tipo **Salario**; con ello generar un Disparador (Trigger) que cada vez que se actualice el campo Salario en tabla Empleado, busque en `Igualar_Salario.empleadoSBase` el `empleado.apellido`; obtener `empleado.salario` y aplicar a cada `Igualar_Salario.empleadoSDestino` que exista en `empleado.apellido` pero donde el salario en `empleado.salario` no sea el mismo asignado.

Otra opción es que en vez de tener salario directo en la tabla; lo manejes como categoria/cargo o similar, creas una tabla catalogo (por ejemplo) con `CCargos (nombreCargo, Salario)` y usar `empleados(codigo,apellido,nombreCargo)`; así solo tendrás que actualizar el cargo a la persona.

## ACTUALIZACIÓN

Por lo que comentas; necesitarias una tabla como la que sugeri arriba (`Igualar_Salario`); entonces en un solo UPDATE:

```
UPDATE EMPLEADOS SET SALARIO=[VALOR NUEVO SALARIO] WHERE (APELLIDO IN (SELECT empleadoSDestino FROM Igualar_Salario WHERE empleadoSBase=[APELLIDO QUE ACTUALIZAS])) OR APELLIDO=[APELLIDO QUE ACTUALIZAS]
```

La tabla que sugiero (bajo nombre) `Igualar_Salario` es por que de algún lugar se debe tomar respecto a quien **X** se igualara el salario que se cambia a **Y**.

Comment: hola RobertoLeOr, los que me indicas es correcto, pero en mi caso me los estan pidiendo en una sola consulta de actualizacion sin usar Trigger, sera que se pueda hacer solo con un update?